# Able to vote twice in Triage

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, triage

In triage, I was given a question. In this case, I marked the question as "Looks OK", and voted up on the question and the answer.

Before moving to the next question, I was given the random checkpoint that shows me how other reviewers marked the question. In this case, my judgement agreed with the consensus.

The checkpoint gives the reviewer a chance to vote on the question (I assume only if they hadn't done so already). But I had already voted, so I would expect I shouldn't be allowed to vote a second time; I was, and the votes do in fact count twice.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35244091

Per Lino's comment, I can confirm that visiting the question page directly shows the correct number of votes. If I voted twice in Triage, the question page only shows the first vote with the correct +1 coloring.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm able to again downvote a triage item, but after reloading the page (or visiting the question directly) the second vote is no longer there. The button on the review screen still shows that I can vote, while the one on the question has the proper state (i.e. already voted + colored in).

Comment: Fortunately, even if this was a real second vote (and the comment above makes it seem like it's not), it would be removed automatically by the (new-ish) serial vote reversal script. Still, you should avoid exploiting this.